# How to evaluate a sequence of impure functions in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

How can I evaluate a list of (impure) functions in Clojure? For instance:

```
[#(println "1") #(println "2") #(println "3")]
```

The expected output is:

```
1
2
3
```

Is there a way to achieve this without using macros? Something like `(map evaluate fns-seq)`, maybe?

(I need this for drawing some graphics using the Clojure.processing API.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
user> (let [fs [#(println "1") #(println "2") #(println "3")]]
         (doseq [f fs] (f)))
1
2
3
nil
```

Answer (score 5):

This will eagerly consume the whole seq, calling all functions for side effects and returning whatever the last one returns:

```
(reduce #(%2) nil [#(println :foo) #(println :bar)])
; => prints :foo, then :bar, then returns nil
```

If you want to hold onto the return values, you can use `reductions` instead:

```
(reductions #(%2) nil [#(println :foo) #(println :bar)])
; => prints :foo, then :bar, then returns (nil nil)
```

`reductions` is found in `clojure.contrib.seq-utils` in Clojure 1.1 and in `clojure.core` in current snapshots of 1.2.

*Update:* Note that `reductions` returns a lazy seq, so it's no improvement over `map` (NB. in `map` you'd want to use `#(%)` rather than `#(%2)`). I mentioned it here mostly for completeness. In fact, I posted the whole answer for completeness, because normally I'd go with the `doseq` approach (see Brian's answer).

Comment: Thanks for your additional comments. I can image, that my "problem" will creep up more often, when dealing with libraries from the imperative Java world. Maybe a macro (dofns fns) would be a nice abstraction, that is currently missing in Clojure.

Answer (score 1):

`(apply pcalls [#(println "1") #(println "2") #(println "3")])` does just that. Just be wary of `pcalls`' parallelism (therefore lack of sequentiality) and lazyness.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, I know, but there's another option.
You could simply `invoke` the functions:

```clj
(defn generate-fns [] 
   [#(println "1") #(println "2") #(println "3")]) 

(dorun (pmap (memfn invoke) (generate-fns)))
```

This allows you to decide in a different context how you would like to execute the functions (say, `pmap`, or [claypoole's](https://github.com/TheClimateCorporation/claypoole) `upmap` for example)