# Something built-in in clojure for --> call an impure function to each element in a sequence?

Tags: clojure, lisp

I was wondering if clojure has something built-in for the following code.
I know I can do `(map (fn [x] (f x)) coll)` and then evaluate the sequence as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088831/how-to-evaluate-a-sequence-of-impure-functions-in-clojure). I don't want to do that.

```
(defn apply-to-all [f coll]
  (f (first coll))
  (if (= (count (rest coll)) 0) 
    nil
    (apply-to-all f (rest coll))))

"example usage"
(apply-to-all println [0 1 2])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(doseq [x [0 1 2]]
  (println x))
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks, and sorry for such a stupid question.. I'm new to clojure.