# How to evaluate sequence of pure functions in Clojure

Tags: clojure, lisp

My question is pretty similar to this one: [How to evaluate a sequence of impure functions in Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088831/how-to-evaluate-a-sequence-of-impure-functions-in-clojure) but instead of impure functions, how can I evaluate sequence of pure functions and get the results as another sequence?

Let's assume we have a vector of functions like:

```
[#(str "a" "b") #(str "c" "d") #(str "e" "f")]
```

And we need an output like this:

```
("ab" "cd" "ef")
```

I've tried something similar to this:

```
(map eval [#(str "a" "b") #(str "c" "d") #(str "e" "f")])
```

but it just returns a vector of function references.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do what you are asking. It depends on whether you want a **lazy sequence or not** (you probably want lazy given there are no side-effects, but you might want no-lazy if there's an intensive computation that you want to cache), or if you want a vector as output (the same as your input). I'll try to follow what you tried to do.

Your map with eval is doing the following with each fn:

```
user=> (eval #(str 1))
#<user$eval1332$fn__1333 user$eval1332$fn__1333@38747597>
```

But you want something like the following:

```
user=> (eval (#(str 1)))
"1"
```

You want eval to have the fn applied, that is: the fn should be the first element of a list. Let's put it in a list:

```
user=> (map (comp eval list) [#(str "a" "b") #(str "c" "d") #(str "e" "f")])
("ab" "cd" "ef")
```

Cool. But instead of eval, you probably want to use apply:

```
user=> (apply #(str 1))
; ArityException Wrong number of args (1)
```

Ups! It failed. `apply` doesn't have a 0-arity overload, but we can pass an empty list:

```
user=> (apply #(str 1) ())
"1"
```

Much better. Let's do it with map:

```
user=> (map #(apply % ()) [#(str "a" "b") #(str "c" "d") #(str "e" "f")])
("ab" "cd" "ef")
```

Or better yet, given your functions receive no arguments, you'd better do as suggested by @Magos:

```
user=> (map #(%) [#(str "a" "b") #(str "c" "d") #(str "e" "f")])                                                                              
("ab" "cd" "ef")
```

Comment: Thanks for complete and quite progressive answer :)

Answer (score 5):

You could use `(fn [f] (f))` or `#(%)` in your `map`.

Comment: Never thought of a function that takes a function as argument and just runs it. It's pretty cool thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`eval` evaluates a Clojure form (i.e., a list containing "code").  You have functions, not forms.

You `map` with `apply`, but `apply` takes both a function and a `seq` of arguments.  Since you have no arguments, you can use the empty vector:

```
(map apply
     [#(str "a" "b") #(str "c" "d") #(str "e" "f")]
     (repeat []))
```

But it would be shorter and probably clearer if you use `for`:

```
(for [f [#(str "a" "b") #(str "c" "d") #(str "e" "f")]]
  (f))
```

Comment: "You have functions, not forms": this is slightly misleading, since functions are forms too; they are constant values like numbers and as such, `eval` acts like `identity`.

Comment: No, a function is a run-time object that is capable of performing some computation.  A form is a description of some piece of code, which may or may not be *describing* a function invocation.  A function is no more a form than a dolphin is a picture of a dolphin.

Comment: `eval` is not a macro but a function which follows the same evaluation rules as other functions; `(f x y)` first evaluates `x` and `y`, and then applies `f` to the respective results. `(eval (fn () ...))` first evaluates the first argument, which returns a function object (IFn), then call the evaluator on that result, which turns out to be the same object. If you had the function quoted, as-in `'(fn () ...)`, then the argument would be an unevaluated expression, a.k.a. a form, and `eval` would create the function object. The difference is between  `(eval dolphin)` and `(eval 'dolphin)`.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**

As [Nathan Davis wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31930142/1562315), `eval` evaluates a clojure *form*:

```
(eval '(+ 1 1)) ;=> 2
```

What does it do to a function? *Nothing!*. `eval` treats functions as literals:

```
((eval +) 1 1) ;=> 2
```

For your case:

```
(def stuff [#(str "a" "b") #(str "c" "d") #(str "e" "f")])
```

... we have

```
(= stuff (map eval stuff)) ;=> true
```

Though

```
(= [#(str "a" "b") #(str "c" "d") #(str "e" "f")]
   (map eval [#(str "a" "b") #(str "c" "d") #(str "e" "f")]))
;=> false
```

... since the corresponding functions are different objects, though identical in operation.

That's why `eval` is useless to you. So follow [Magos's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31929606/1562315).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's worth to have a look at `pcalls` and/or `pvalues`

```
(pcalls #(str "a" "b") #(str "c" "d") #(str "e" "f"))
;=> ("ab" "cd" "ef")
```

Please note that `pcalls` is using `future` inside!